# mean mode and median for $\chi^2_3\$

Tags: statistics, matlab

My [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4346556/meadian-mode-and-mean-of-chi2-with-3-degrees-of-freedom) has been closed as it didn't show my own attempts. So here is one:
a code for Matlab I have tried for **mean** was this:

diff([.005  .01  .025  .05  .10  .20  .25  .30  .40  .50  .60  .70  .75  .80  .90  .95  .975  .99  .995])*diff([.0717  .1148  .2158  .3518  .5844  1.005  1.213  1.424  1.869  2.366  2.946  3.665  4.108  4.642  6.251  7.815  9.348  11.34  12.84])'

It should yield 3 but it gave 0.6675.
What is wrong with this `diff` ?

I also need median and mode, besides p.d.f.

Here is copied my OQ:

\begin{array}{c|r}
p & .005 & .01 & .025 & .05 & .10 & .20 & .25 & .30 & .40 & .50 & .60 & .70 & .75 & .80 & .90 & .95 & .975 & .99 & .995\\
\hline
m=3 & .0717 & .1148 & .2158 & .3518 & .5844 & 1.005 & 1.213 & 1.424 & 1.869 & 2.366 & 2.946 & 3.665 & 4.108 & 4.642 & 6.251 & 7.815 & 9.348 & 11.34 & 12.84
\end{array}

Comment: What does the second "diff" even mean?

Comment: @BrianMoehring diff(X), for a vector X, is [X(2)-X(1)  X(3)-X(2) ... X(n)-X(n-1)].

Comment: I was specifically asking about the second "diff", not about the definition of "diff" in MATLAB.  That is, what does this describe: ........ diff([.0717 .1148 .2158 .3518 .5844 1.005 1.213 1.424 1.869 2.366 2.946 3.665 4.108 4.642 6.251 7.815 9.348 11.34 12.84])

Comment: @BrianMoehring I was trying to compute p.d.f. from c.d.f. by this command.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Even this doesn't give 3: `(diff([.005  .01  .025  .05  .10  .20  .25  .30  .40  .50  .60  .70  .75  .80  .90  .95  .975  .99  .995 1]))*([.0717  .1148  .2158  .3518  .5844  1.005  1.213  1.424  1.869  2.366  2.946  3.665  4.108  4.642  6.251  7.815  9.348  11.34  12.84])'
`

Comment: It never was going to give an answer of 3 exactly.  The discretized form you've written will always give a lower bound for the mean of a random variable supported on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Good. Could you give me an intuition why always **lower** and never say 3.1 ?

Comment: As a question: What is the smallest random variable supported on $[0,\infty)$ which has the same table of CDF values?  (or more directly if you've studied probability, think about the simple functions that approximate a non-negative random variable from below)

Comment: @BrianMoehring The one which is eventually =1 ?